# Add caption for videoview in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

How to add Caption "Tap on me to play video" for videoview in android?

Comment: Is it some text you want to add on top of the video?

Comment: not exactly on video before playing video like by seeing the caption user will tap on that

Comment: Post your existing code here. or create a RelativeLayout with VideoView and TextView. Add onClickListener to the TextView and overide the onClick(View v) method to start playing the video.

Comment: <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight=".65" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0px" android:id="@+id/videoviewlayout" android:layout_gravity="center" > <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0px" android:text="Tap on Me to play Video" android:layout_centerInParent="true" > </TextView> <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> </VideoView> </RelativeLayout>with this code video is playing fine but before playing at exactly center of video view i need a caption

Comment: can you please edit the question itself with the code (Activity/Xml).

Answer (score 0):

put a textview over your videoView or what are you using to view videos and set onClickListener and on click, hide the textView and start play your video

Comment: how to put textview over videoview is my question